# Use Anaconda Navigator with Miniconda's `conda`

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I use miniconda due to SSD disk space considerations.

Both miniconda and anaconda use `conda` as the underlying package manager.

Is it possible to use [Anaconda's Navigator](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/navigator/) package manager to manage `conda` as installed by miniconda?

If not, is there any GUI to miniconda's `conda`?

[This page](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator) says to install `anaconda-navigator` by:

```
conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
```

The failure log is below:

---

```
% conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator --dry-run                                                                                                                13.8s | 18-10-18 15:42:07
Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 227, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 574, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        raise Response304ContentUnchanged()
    conda.core.subdir_data.Response304ContentUnchanged

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force,
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 518, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 451, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 180, in solve_final_state
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 592, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 215, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = query_all(spec)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 184, in query_all
        return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 95, in query
        self.load()
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 149, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 233, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 280, in _read_local_repdata
        _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
      File "/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 369, in _process_raw_repodata_str
        info['fn'] = fn
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

`$ /home/ravi/bin/conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator --dry-run`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3
                 GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3:/home/ravi/.gem/ru
                          by/2.3.3:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3
       GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=:
        GLADE_MODULE_PATH=:
        GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH=:
                   GOPATH=/home/ravi/.local/share/go
              LADSPA_PATH=/usr/lib/ladspa:/usr/lib/ladspa
          MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
                     PATH=/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3/bin:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3/bin:/home/ra
                          vi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3/bin:/home/ravi/bin:/home/ravi/.local/share/minicond
                          a3/bin:/home/ravi/.local/share/virtualenvs/py3/bin:/home/ravi/.local/s
                          hare/npm/bin:/home/ravi/.local/share/go/bin:/home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.3.3
                          /bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default
                          /bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/l
                          ib/systemd:/home/ravi/.cabal/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/sit
                          e_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
           PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/ravi/.local/share/python
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
 TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH=/home/ravi/.local/share/tmux/plugins/
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/ravi/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/ravi/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/ravi/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/ravi/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/4.16.18-1-MANJARO manjaro/18.0.0-rc glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : /home/ravi/.netrc
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
Upload successful.
```

Comment: conda is the package manager, Navigator is just GUI for conda. miniconda is just anaconda with only default packages installed, including conda. have you install miniconda & navigator?

Comment: @cryptonome I've updated the question with the failure output of running the recommended install command.

Comment: there's only one channel for anaconda-navigator afaik, you can exclude `-c anaconda` flag & just use `conda install anaconda-navigator` instead.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Conda, I suggest you report it on GitHub, although it appears that conda itself has already reported something.